# Servlet filter which is mapped on /home is not invoked when I open /home.xhtml

Tags: jsf, authentication, servlet-filters

I am new to Java Enterprise Edition. I started learning from some YouTube videos, and recently started   reading http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/    I finished chapter 15.

I tried to make my own filter.

I didn't use Java Servlet class. Because I want to use JSF pages, and as far as I know it is only possible to use Managed Beans with JSF pages, Whereas Servlet classes work with JSP. It is OK.

As far as I know the usefulness of login filter:
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info

> [...] This is particularly useful when you have multiple pages for which
>   you'd like to check the logged-in user. Instead of copypasting the
>   same logic over all pages, you can use a Filter to have it in a single
>   place.

It is useful (as I know) in the case when a user type the URL **directly** into the browser for a page which   require logged in user, so the filter will redirect him to the login page or continue if he is logged in.

I searched for any simple example to learn from but didn't find. I will put my simple example:

I have two JSF pages
one is named home.xhtml (which require logged in user)
the other one is named login.xhtml (filter must redirect to it if non-logged users seek home)

login.xhtml:

```
  <h:form>
     <h:panelGrid columns="2">
     <h:outputLabel value="name:"/> <h:inputText value="#{user.name}"/>
     <h:outputLabel value="password:"/> <h:inputSecret value="#{user.password}"/>
     </h:panelGrid>
     <h:commandButton id="btn"  value="login" action="#{user.login()}"/>
  </h:form>
```

home.xhtml:

```
<h:body>
   Hello #{user.name}. You are welcome
</h:body>
```

User:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class User implements Serializable
{
   String name;
   String password;
   Authentication authentication;

   public User()
   {
      authentication = new Authentication();
   }

    //Getters and Setters for name and password.

   public String login()
   {
      if (this.getName().equals("user") &&(this.getPassword().equals("1234")))
      {
         authentication.setLoggedIn(true);
         FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
         context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("auth", authentication);
         return "home";
      }
      else
      {
         authentication.setLoggedIn(false);
         FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
         context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("auth", authentication);
         return "login";
      }
   }
}
```

Authentication:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Authentication implements Serializable
{

   private boolean authenticated;

   public Authentication()
   {
      authenticated = false;
   }

   public boolean isLoggedIn()
   {
      return authenticated;
   }

   public void setLoggedIn(boolean authenticated)
   {
      this.authenticated = authenticated;
   }

}
```

LoginFilter:

```
@WebFilter(value = "/home")
public class LoginFilter implements Filter
{

   @Override
   public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException
   {
      //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
   }

   @Override
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException
   {
      HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
      Authentication auth = (Authentication) req.getSession().getAttribute("auth");

      if (auth != null && auth.isLoggedIn())
      {
         System.out.println("Filter is working");
         chain.doFilter(request, response);
      } else
      {
         System.out.println("Filter is working");
         HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
         res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml");
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void destroy()
   {
      //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
   }
}
```

faces-config:

```
   <navigation-rule>
      <from-view-id>/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
      <navigation-case>
         <from-outcome>home</from-outcome>
         <to-view-id>/home.xhtml</to-view-id>
         <redirect/>
      </navigation-case>
      <navigation-case>
         <from-outcome>login</from-outcome>
         <to-view-id>/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
         <redirect/>
      </navigation-case>
   </navigation-rule>
```

web.xml:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

---

Now when I type the URL of home.xhtml page (after clearing history & cookies) into the browser it is assumed to   redirect me to **login** page. But instead it goes to home with empty value for name:
`Hello #{user.name}. You are welcome` is rendered as `Hello . You are welcome`

Even `System.out.println("Filter is working");` not print anything.

Comment: The annotation @WebFilter, added in Servlet 3.0. what is your servlet version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the filter is called? If there is nothing printed to `System.out` I guess not. The problem might be the servlet mapping.

You specified this:

```
@WebFilter(value = "/home")
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {...}
```

I think this only matches the url `/home`. Try to use `/*` or `/home*` (which is very limiting, I would not recommend it) instead.

Another thing: If you get `Hello #{user.name}. You are welcome` as output, then the `FacesServlet` is probably not called. This might have two reasons:

1. You use the wrong mapping. Try to call the page with `/faces/home.xhtml` or `/home.jsf` instead. The url depends on the type of mapping you have in the `web.xml`.
2. The `FacesServlet` is not configured correctly/at all in the `web.xml`.

Comment: I changed `/home` to `/home*` But Filter not working and `System.out` not printing.  But I changed `/home` to `/*` , now `System.out` is printing, but the browser shows me <This web page has a redirect loop> <The web page at http://localhost:8080/LoginFilter_Simple/login.xhtml has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem.If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.>.  So how to avoid the **loop**

Comment: With `/*` the filter is called for `login.xhtml` too and redirects to the same page over and over again. You could manually check for `login.xhtml` in the filter (like `req.getRequestURI().contains("login.xhtml")`) to avoid the redirect in this case. Alternatively you can put all pages that need login in a special path like `/secure` and map the filter to this path `/secure/*`.

Comment: OK, I added another check so it become `if ((auth != null && auth.isLoggedIn()) || (req.getRequestURI().contains("login.xhtml")))`. It now **works ok**, when I type to `home.xhtml` it redirects to `login.xhtml` **(as expected)** or if I type `login.xhtml` it goes to it **(as expected)**. **But** the `login.xhtml` page is totally blank (no `labels` no `inputTexts` no `button`). why they **aren't rendered!?**.

Comment: Do you have a mapping for `FacesServlet` in your `web.xml`? I think you have no mapping or you use the wrong URL to address your views in the browser (see point 1 in the answer). Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gjaeu/index.html.

Comment: Please don't use the `contains()` check on login page, this is extremely unsafe as it would match many more other URLs than just login page. Rather use the `equals()` check.

Comment: `FacesServlet` Mapping is already done. Is there other thing to fix?

Comment: What's your mapping? Depending on that you might use the wrong url in the browser.

Comment: I added the `web.xml` to the question body above. is there something to fix.

Comment: Depending on your mapping, you must call the pages with `/faces/home.xhtml` and /faces/login.xhtml` (also for the redirect!!).